# Scraping indicator results from tradingview - steps and instructions

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Before you deem this question duplicated, I read all the questions with the topic of scraping and tradingview, none of those question covered the points here completely, so I asked my own question. Thank you very much for your time and help.

I want to extract indicator results from TradingView's website. There are a few challenges:

1. I need to log in.
2. I have to open multiple sessions for different
   symbols (This is an important step).
3. I need to add indicators to each session (This is an important and complicated step).
4. I must click the "data window" button.
5. I want to scrape the results from the
   data window.

I am completely new to scraping, and after a bit of research, I understand that one of the best ways that can handle these steps is Selenium. Although, I do not have any clue on if all these steps are possible to do in Selenium + Python, and if they are, how much time will they require. Now, I am not asking about the time, but:

1. First, if it is possible to do these steps in Selenium
2. It would be amazing if you can give me a few keywords on how can I complete these steps in Selenium.

UPDATE:

Clarifications on the question:
1- I understand that scraping is not he easiest option, as I have developed over 200 indicators and candle patterns before in Python, and now there are reasons that I have to use scraping.
2- I am new to scraping, not new to programming. Please write your full answer guide without considering my expertise level.
3- I do not need any code, I just want keywords on what will I do and what will I use in every step.

Comment: No one has any guide for this?

Comment: Please note that here on SO we don't just "write code for you". You'll have to [edit] your question to include what you have tried so far to include a [mre]

Comment: @MendelG As stated in the question, i am not looking for any code, as it would be impossible to write a helping code here. My question is about the procedure and the steps on this project, not the codes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to do the same since the indicators data is from a invite-only script on tradingview.

here is my plan:

1. Using Selenium to get the data ready on the canvas of page.
2. Save the canvas to an image.
3. The result for my case is on a data table so I will create an script to do the OCR the extract the data from the image.

Updated:

I found that tradingview has a `Data Window` includes all indicators data which we could use to do scraping. It's located at `Object Tree and Data Window` on left menu we could open it.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It was an interesting solution. Thanks for the insight. Unfortunately I did not accept this project due to not knowing how to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about scraping but have you checked [pynescript python library](https://pypi.org/project/pynescript/)? it's supposed to convert "Pine Script" to "AST" that you can execute in python. so if you have the pine script source code of that indicator, you can potentially use this library to run the indicator code in python and get the indicator values that you are trying to scrape.

Comment: I have not seen nor worked with this library. Thank you for the suggestion I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is called an API. It is basically an endpoint for programs to access a website or service's functionality. You can take a look at [TradingView's API](https://www.tradingview.com/rest-api-spec/) and see if that helps you.

You mention that you want to use python. The wrapper library for TradingView's API in python is [`tradingview-ta`](https://pypi.org/project/tradingview-ta/). Install it bu running:

```bash
pip install tradingview-ta
```

Here is an example script

```py
from tradingview_ta import TA_Handler, Interval, Exchange

tesla = TA_Handler(
    symbol="TSLA",
    screener="america",
    exchange="NASDAQ",
    interval=Interval.INTERVAL_1_DAY
)
print(tesla.get_analysis().summary)
# Example output: {"RECOMMENDATION": "BUY", "BUY": 8, "NEUTRAL": 6, "SELL": 3}
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully! I do not understand why using the API helps my problem of scraping the indicator results of the chart!

Comment: @Vahid Using an API is your only option. Websites are specifically designed to prevent scraping. Why do you think the capcha is there? To prevent bots from scraping. If you want the data, you WILL need an API.

Comment: In the API docs, I could not see any indication that it can give me the indicators data. I do not need the price data, I can get them from the brokers' APIs, but the data of the indicators, are not available as far as I know.

Comment: @Vahid Indicators are just scripts that run on top of the price data. For example https://www.investopedia.com/terms/r/rsi.asp

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, but I understand what is an indicator. I have developed over 200 different indicators, but the two that I am trying to scrape the data, was too comlicated to convert to python, and after I converted them, they produced different data from tradingview. Also they do not exist in any library. So I have to rely on the Tradingview data, and for that, I need to scrape the data from data window.

Answer (score 0):

As Umar said, the API would probably be the best method for this. TradingView makes scraping data pretty difficult, using websockets that are not intuitive to scrape unless you are very skilled in web scraping.

I support Umar's suggestion of API use; you can query the API as he described, and gather the market data for a given stock or coin. Then, you could use free packages like `talib` to transform your data:

```
tesla['SMA20'] = talib.SMA(tesla['Close'], timeperiod=20)
tesla['EMA20'] = talib.EMA(tesla['Close'], timeperiod=20)
tesla['ADX'] = talib.ADX(tesla['High'], msft['Low'], msft['Close'], timeperiod=14)
```

The use of `talib` here makes it effortless to get the indicators that you are looking for. It will only take one API query, and a few calls to talib, to transfrom the data into indicators, instead of writing a complex Selenium script that may get blocked by Tradingview.

EDIT: If you insist on scraping, here is an overview (there very well could be details missing here, as I have not written the code for this):

The main principle when using Selenium is getting familiar with the "inspect" tool in your browser. There, you can find the code of the website, and can direct Selenium to select certain elements, and perform actions on those elements, by using the website code. For example, you can select an Xpath, assign it to a variable, and then send keys. I will detail that process below.

1.Set up your Selenium driver by downloading Selenium. You should (as is typically true) download the newest version, as you will not need to specify the Driver path, which speeds up setup.

2.To log in, you will direct Selenium to tradingview- probably tradingview.com/chart if you want to scrape indicators. You can click on "login", or the hamburger menu that leads to "login", by a method like

```
element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Login')]")
```

You can select elements by many different methods; this is just one example.

3.Once at the login screen, you can send your credentials through the "send_keys" method:

```
element.send_keys("YOUR_USERNAME")
```

You can repeat this process for the password, then select the "enter" button and submit a click by using `.click()` .

4.Inspect the data window, just as you did for the login buttons, and submit a click to that element.

5.To scrape certain results or indicators, you will need to inspect them, and may need to click on them, but can do so with methods stated above. It is unclear to me what you are trying to scrape here. Do you want the line, or a value that is returned by the indicators? One option could be using Seleniums option to `save_screenshot(‘ss.png’)` to take a screenshot of the view and then process the data elsewhere.

Comment: I know talib, it does not have the two indicators that I need, I first converted them to python, but they do not produce the same signals. So I HAVE to use the data from tradingview.
My problem is obvious, and my question is clear. If you know about scraping, please share your ideas. If don't, I appreciate your time and answers.
Also about websockets, I do not need the price data, so there is no need for me to use websockets. I need the indicator data that exist in the data window section. So scraping would solve my problem.

Comment: @Vahid I know all about scraping, and I am telling you that if you are asking the question like this, then scraping tradingview will be too complex for you. You can calculate all indicators yourself. Use the API, transform the data either with talib or by learning the calculations.

Comment: Too complex or easy, does not matter. This is the way to go. If you know the steps I mentioned in the question, please edit your answer to include guidelines for that. I have a 2-3 week window for this project, so I have all the time to finish it.

Comment: @Vahid I updated my answer significantly with some steps. It is not comprehensive- i.e. I did not describe driver setup in the code, but theres a million answers to that question online.

Comment: Thanks for the update, however you still neglected main parts of my question. I think I have not written the question clear enough. So I updated it to be more clear.

Comment: @Vahid sorry but I do not see what I left out

Comment: So, if you read the question carefully, I specifically ask for keywords on those steps, specially the opening different tabs and adding indicators. I can not see anything related to these two fields in the answer.